# Re-atched a FC Tape Drive part of Tape Library - how to update Backup Exec?

Tags: scsi, backup-exec, san

I've re-patched a FC Tape Drive that's part of a Dell ML6010 Tape Library who's link failed due to a failed HBA in the server. I've re-patched so it'll come into the only working HBA in the server now, and zoned it in correctly at the switch, and the operating system WS2003 can see the tape drive with it's new SCSI Address in Device Manager.

The drive still appears in Backup Exec with it's old SCSI address (right-click drive, SCSI Information) - but these fields are non editable.

Is there a way to update the drive config to tell it the new SCSI address?

I assumed I'd be able to add it in BE as a new tape drive as part of the library, at the least, even if I couldn't update the SCSI address of the existing device. But going

Devices -> Storage Devices -> Device Pools -> All Devices (right Click, Add Device) comes up with the message:

> There are no other devices available to be added to this device pool at this time.

I'm hoping I'm missing something simple!

Comment: For Clarification: Trying to make an existing tape drive in Backup Exec to work, via a different HBA, which appears as a differnt SCSI Target in the OS, WS2003. The OS sees the drive, but I don't know how to make Backup Exec see it.

Comment: I've just found that restarting the backup exec servies did the trick, so please don't waste your time answering this - I'm unable to answer it for 8 hours, since I'm new to SuperUser. Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that what I needed to do was restart the Backup Exec services via:

Storage Devices -> Server Name (Right Click) -> Backup Exec Services

> "Restart All Services"

Once reconnected to Backup Exec, the existing drive just appeared as normal, and the "SCSI Information" has updated to reflect the new HBA "Port", Bus, Target ID and LUN.